# cannot find a string in x64dbg even when using search all strings

Tags: x64dbg, x86-64

I am trying to debug a program for testing but for some reason i can NOT find any strings related to registeration like Registered, Unregistered,Blocked in x64dbg,  i can see all these strings in the interface of the program but not in the X64dbg, although i have already tried search ALL strings, what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the application is packed using a packer or the strings are encrypted. I would first see if it is packed using a tool like PEiD or Detect It Easy.